# App Crashing when running Meteor + Telescope app on Mac "Picker is not defined"

Tags: meteor, telescope

I'm very new to Telescope and Meteor. I'm trying to launch both from my mac terminal and this is the issue I'm getting in my browser. I haven't changed any files.

Any idea what could it mean? and how to solve it?
Thank you,
Pierre

```
    /Users/pierre/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
ReferenceError: Picker is not defined
    at meteorInstall.Telescope.packages.telescope-api.lib.server.routes.js (Telescope/packages/telescope-api/lib/server/routes.js:2:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
    at /Users/pierre/projectname/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:13410:1
    at /Users/pierre/projectname/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/pierre/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/pierre/projectname/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: As you can see in [the repo](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/tree/master/packages) there is no package or directory named "telescope-api" anymore, so it sounds like you're not running the latest version of Telescope. I would suggest reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Sacha! That was it. My app is now running. 1) Install Telescope from GitHub 2) Install Meteor inside the Telescope folder 3) Install NPM Packages 4) Run Meteor!